# Block Internet Access for a specific app (root)

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-internet

I am trying to force speech recognition to work offline in Android 4.1+. Google doesn't allow developers to specify if they want recognition to be done offline, but if the internet connection of a device is off then it will run in offline mode.

I know that for root users, this is possible through iptables and is seen in apps like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.firewall, but I'm pretty unaware of how this works and would love any help from Linux or Android devs.

Comment: I am not sure speech recognition will work offline.

Comment: @HariRam I know it works because if I turn the internet connection of the whole device off, then it still works...